# How do I make a restful api query in a custom polymer element and present it to a polymer dom-repeater?

Tags: jquery, json, api, rest, polymer

I am trying to call a restful api from a custom polymer element and print it in a repeating template. I think the problem is to do with the format of the json data received and the dom-repeat not being able to read it properly.

```
        <template>
            <input value="{{searchString::input}}">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{test}}" as="test">
                <paper-card class="cover-item">
                    <div>{{test.id}}, {{test.title}}</div>
                </paper-card>

            </template>
        </template>
```

And the polymer element is:

```
                   test: {
                        type: Array,

                        value: $.getJSON("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"), function (data) {
                            var items2 = [];
                            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                return items
                            })
                        }

                    }
```

The console shows

```
[dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for `items`,
```

I'm not exactly sure what is wrong and the polymer documentation isn't really helping.

Many thanks

Comment: Try add to the test value general function, which returns your array: `fucntion() {$.getJSON("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"), function (data) {
                            var items2 = [];
                            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                return items
                            })
                        } return "your array";}`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look into the [iron-ajax](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) element.

Example:

```html
<iron-ajax url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="item">
  <paper-card class="cover-item">
    <div>{{item.id}}, {{item.title}}</div>
  </paper-card>
</template>
```